# Why is code still running after return

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, event-handling

I have some code in `CellValueChanged` event of `datagridview`, the full code is below:

```
private void RationFormulationdgv_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (FirstShown == true)
    {
        return;
    }

    // I write this part to avoid inserting wrong character like 
    //negative number or letters but the problem is when user inter
    //negative number the `messageBox` will pup up but the coeds after
    //that still runs and insert wrong numbers into my database.
    //and this messageBox 
    //> MessageBox.Show("ErrorCellValueChangedEndCatch"); 
    //will pup up at the end.

    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0 && PreValue != null)
    {
        bool IsCorrect = true;
        string Value = RationFormulationdgv[e.ColumnIndex, 
        e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

        if (Value == string.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Insert a Number!";

            IsCorrect = false;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                Double CellValue = Double.Parse(Value);

                if (CellValue < 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please use ONLY positive Number";

                    //@media when in debug I step into this line it goes
                    //on first line of event, and coeds are executing 
                    //from the first
                    RationFormulationdgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].
                    Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = PreValue;

                    IsCorrect = false;

                    // my point in this return doesn't work
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please insert ONLY Numbers");

                IsCorrect = false;

                RationFormulationdgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].
                Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = PreValue;

                return;
            }
        }

        if (!IsCorrect)
        {
            RationFormulationdgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].
            Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = PreValue;

            RationFormulationdgv.CurrentCell.Selected = false;

            return;
        }

        PreValue = null;
    }

    try
    {
        RationFormulationDBConnection.UpdateFeedsDetails(RationFormulationdgv);

        RationFormulationDBConnection.
        SetFeedsIntoRationFormulationdgv
        (RationFormulationdgv, RationTotaldgv);

        RationFormulationDBConnection.SetRationTotaldgv(RationTotaldgv);
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ErrorCellValueChangedEndCatch");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking why `FirstShown` is not equal to `true`?

Comment: What is executing after return?

Comment: @EdPlunkett No that return work good,
I'll edit the question and show the return that doesn't work

Comment: Also remember that ASP.NET is stateless, so any form properties or local variables are reset with each request unless you save them in the view or page state somewhere.

Comment: why codes are still run after return in c# ?

Comment: What value `Value` in watch window?

Comment: @media I edited the question.

Comment: @viveknuna that is my problem

Comment: @EdPlunkett Sorry I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Variable named Value. What is its value? What is it equal to?

Comment: @DStanley I think you mean the FirstShown variable?
this part of the coed works good, the variable change to false in Form_Shown event

Comment: @EdPlunkett it's equal to number or character that user inter into a cell of datagridview

Comment: Did you make sure it is what you think it is?

Comment: @EdPlunkett yes in debug the value is equal to what the user interned

Comment: What is FirstShown? have you checked it in debug mode to be confident about its value to contain false?

Comment: @media when this form is load the datagridview will fill by form_load event so I had to do this trick to prevent these codes from running at the first time, and I checked, it remain false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `CellBeginEdit` event must be like this:

```
object PreValue = null;
bool StopAction = false;
private void RationFormulationdgv_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    PreValue = RationFormulationdgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;

    try
    {
        if (Convert.ToDouble(PreValue) >= 0)
        {
           StopAction = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ErrorInSetingStopAction");
    }
}
```

And then `CellValueChnaged` event must be like this:

```
private void RationFormulationdgv_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (FirstShown == true)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (PreValue != null && StopAction==false)
    {
        string Value = RationFormulationdgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

        if (Value == string.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Insert a Number!");

            StopAction = true;
            RationFormulationdgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].
            Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = PreValue;   
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                Double CellValue = Double.Parse(Value);

                if (CellValue < 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please use ONLY positive Number");

                    StopAction = true;
                    RationFormulationdgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].
                    Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = PreValue;

                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please insert ONLY Numbers");

                StopAction = true;
                RationFormulationdgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].
                Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = PreValue;
            }
        }
    }

    if (StopAction)
    {
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        RationFormulationDBConnection RFDBC = new
        RationFormulationDBConnection();

        RFDBC.UpdateFeedsDetails(RationFormulationdgv);

        RFDBC.SetFeedsIntoRationFormulationdgv
        (RationFormulationdgv, RationTotaldgv);
        RFDBC.SetRationTotaldgv(RationTotaldgv);
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ErrorCellValueChangedEndCatch");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually your code is incomplete but there should be a reason for this evident. After facing `return;` the method have to be terminated. I suggest you to have the following code and use break point to see whether `FirstShown` is true or false:

```
private void RationFormulationdgv_CellValueChanged(object sender,
DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (FirstShown == true)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if (FirstShown == false)
    {
        //The code that have to be run
    }
}
```

Edit:
Look here:

```
RationFormulationdgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = PreValue;
```

In this part of your program you are changing the value of cells of the grid. So immediately after changing the value of your grid, `RationFormulationdgv_CellValueChanged` which is fired when the values of the cells of grid are changed. So whenever your current executing line of program reaches to the mentioned changing-cell-value-line, the event is executed again. An alternative can be using `Leave` Handler to validate which will be fired when the grid lost the focus.

Comment: I don't have any problem with FirstShown variable, that part works good.
my problem is with that return in if (CellValue < 0) block that I pointed it with comment in question

Comment: Hey man :) I got the reason. wait for a while to update the answer

Comment: tnk a lot I'll be wating

Comment: that's is my exact problem, I want to prevent prevent inserting wrong data to database and also when user insert wrong number the previous number (that is already is in database shows in the cell, now what's the solution??

Comment: Are you using `WPF` or `WinForms`?

Comment: I use Win Forms

Comment: You are using a wrong handler based on your attempt. You can use something like the event `dataGridView.Leave` which is fired when the focus is lost or another handler that can not be invoked in the current handler and be invoked in an appropriate time which is needed to validate. e.g. in `TextBox` although you have `textchanged` event but for validating that changes the value of the `textbox` some handlers like  `Leave`

Comment: tnx, but my datagridview has calculating cells that i want when a value changed, value of those cells change automatically, I tried CellEndEdit before but the problem wasn't solve

Comment: Why can't you use `Leave` handler? It can does the same work.

Comment: I will try that and tell you what I've got, tnx a lot :)

Comment: Hi, using CellLeave had it's own issue, check my answer, finally I get what I want :)

Comment: @SaraniO I'm happy you found your solution